# Haskell function to work on integer tuple

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm have just started learning Haskell and am trying to create a function that performs several checks on a **tuple** containing 6 integers.
These checks include:

1. all digits are different;
2. alternate digits are even and odd, or odd and even;
3. alternate digits differ by more than two;
4. the first and middle pairs of digits form numbers that are both multiples of the last

The problem is that I can attempt this and have some working functions like

```
contains e [] = False
contains e (x:xs)
    |   x == e = True
    |   otherwise = contains e xs

unique :: [Int] -> Bool
unique [] = True
unique (x:xs)
    |   contains x xs   = False
    |   otherwise       = unique xs
```

for the first requirement, but as you can see this relies on using a **list** rather than a tuple.
I would appreciate it if someone could help me with how to create these functions for tuples instead, as well as any code efficiency suggestions.

Comment: This is not a tuple, this is a list.

Comment: You can convert a tuple to a list however.

Comment: That's literally the point of the question

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a 6-tuple to a list, with:

```
tuple6ToList :: (a, a, a, a, a, a) -> [a]
tuple6ToList (a, b, c, d, e, f) = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

and then run the checks on the list for example. This is likely simpler, since one can then recurse on the list, whereas for a tuple it would mean that you "unwind" the checks into individual checks on the elements.

Comment: Thank you. Since the question I was working on was worded to specifically talk about tuples I was wondering if there was an easy tuple method I didn't know about and so hesitant to just use lists and convert, but this makes sense.